# Laravel API to returns json response

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm developing and College project, It should be a platform that serve and Web and Mobile Front-En. I decided to use Laravel 5.1, my idea was to use laravel as an excelent hardcore php backend to serve this platform, I wanted to develope APIsRest with laravel and comsume the services on both web and mobile front-end. My point is: I don't wanna use blade templating engine, because returning "views, instance objects, etc" my mobile front won't understand responses, that's why I want to orientated my APIs to return JSONs messanges, so I can handle them on each front.

1) First at all I wanna ask you guys if is it a good idea?
2) how can I retrieve the error php messages send by laravel to send them back to views (mobile-web front) as JSONs?

Example: Right now I'm trying to finish the "Login-Register" module of my project. I'm trying to use the advantages of Authentication Laravel Module, and now I am stack on postLogin, because i don't know how to handle the error and send it back to front as JSON.

```
 public function postIngresar(Request $request)
{

    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();


    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return response()->json(*$this->sendLockoutResponse($request));
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);


    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => 'true',
            'message' => 'Logeo logrado exitosamente'
        ]);
    }


    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }


    return response()->json($this->getFailedLoginMessage());

    }
```

is there any way to handle all error and exception as JSON messages? It'll will help me A LOT.

thank you so much by reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about [`Exception Handling`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#the-exception-handler) section of the Laravel docs, but to save you the time, here is the name of the method that will be responsible for returning json representation of your errors:

> All exceptions are handled by the **App\Exceptions\Handler** class. This class contains two methods: **report and render**. The **render** method is responsible for converting a given exception into an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser. By default, the exception is passed to the base class which generates a response for you. However, you are free to check the exception type or return your own custom response

Answer (score 1):

The `LoginController` uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which has a method `sendFailedLoginResponse` which is responsible for the error message redirect upon authentication failure as follows:

```
 protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{

    if ( ! User::where('email', $request->email)->first() ) {
        return response()->json([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.email')
            ]);           
    }

    if ( ! User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first() ) {
       return response()->json([
                'password' => Lang::get('auth.email')
            ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It is a good way to get failedLogin error as JSON, even though I am trying to generalize all exceptions || errors to return them as JSON.